# NetworkError: 404 Not Found

Tags: php, jquery, html

Why get downvoted ? this is second Time i get downvoted .. please at least tell me the reason . so that I can improve it

i m using jquery get method to send data from html to php (Both are hosted on localhost/Site1)

Edit: I am getting the html page fine on LocalHost. FireBug shows the following error, when I click on `Button`.

```
`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/new2.php?name=Zara"`
```

Html:(my_html.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.get( 
             "http://localhost/new2.php",
             { name: "Zara" },
             function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }

          );
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="stage" style="background-color:blue;">
          STAGE
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code :(new2.php)

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

I read related questions / posts, it was suggested that I write proper url (in which web app your html is host)

So I changed my url to `localhost/site1/new2.php` But now it shows error `$ not defined`.

Please help.

Comment: Using the command line ping http://localhost/ what do you get?

Are you using Developer Tools or Firebug to help you debug? Look at the Network or Net tab and see where the AJAX call is going.

Comment: localHost is fine . I am getting the html Page fine . I am using Firebug . when I cliked on Button . that in error console this error comes

Comment: `$ not defined` means there is an issue with loading the jQuery library.

Comment: error $ not defined because JQuery library not defined replace `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> ` To `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I changed the script . error is same

Comment: Why get downvoted ? this is second Time i get downvoted .. please at least tell me the reason . so that I can improve it

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is incorrect.

You say:

> (Both are hosted on localost/Site1)

But your code says:

```
"http://localhost/new2.php",
```

It should be:

```
"http://localhost/Site1/new2.php",
```

Comment: I tried to do that already . it is giving library error as i mentioned ..i changed the library and Test it . it is loading fine in browser

Comment: Just remember it's case sensitive if running in a unix environment, so make sure your url is correct.

Comment: URL is perfectly Fine .. Should i embed php in HMTL ?

Comment: No need. The error has nothing to do with PHP. It can't find the file. Which means there's something wrong with the URL. That's the only real explanation I can think of.

Comment: Also try specifying a relative path. So instead of `"http://localhost/new2.php"` try just `"new2.php"`.

Comment: same result . no diffrence

Answer (score 0):

hIf the site is located at `localhost/Site1` - surely the GET needs to point to `"http://localhost/Site1/new2.php"`??

Answer (score 0):

> (Both are hosted on localost/Site1)

```
"http://localhost/new2.php"
```

Maybe should be

```
"http://localhost/Site1/new2.php" ?
```

If you get 404 through Firebug / Browser, the script def is NOT located under `http://localhost/new2.php`, simple as that. Check the path of the files and where you did  upload them.

Answer (score 0):

I test that $.get() function is working fine with .txt and .asp files....I believe some installation might need to be done in IIS for php.. anyway i understood the functionality of $.Get() function . which was my purpose